# Make C++ std::string end at specified character?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, c++14

Let's say I am traversing a string of length n. I want it to end at a specific character that fulfils some conditions. I know that **C style strings** can be terminated at the **i'th** position by simply assigning the character **'\0'** at position **i** in the character array.

Is there any way to achieve the same result in an **std::string** (C++ style string)? I can think of substr, erase, etc. but all of them are linear in their complexity, which I cannot afford to use.

TL;DR, is there any "end" character for an std::string? Can I make the end iterator point to the current character somehow?

Comment: you can get an iterator to point to anywhere you want to use it as the end. Just do `std::advance(str.begin(), n)` and use that as the end.

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting substring? And what should happen to the remainder of the string?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I didn't need the remainder of the string, just needed the part before the end character.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Another intuitive answer, thanks, but it would take linear time, just like all other suggestions :) And I'm not even sure we can simply assign iterators to string::end which might be a const iterator.

Comment: @KushalAgrawal: What I meant is if you have considered memory consumption. A C string does not really become smaller if you set a character to null. The remainder still occupies memory until `free` is called on the first character's address. This may or may not be important for your current problem.

Comment: @KushalAgrawal complexity for `std::advance` is constant if the iterator satisfies "RandomAccessIterator" which `std::string::iterator` does

Comment: Good question, but you accepted the wrong answer. Either Kerrek SB's or Nicol Bolas was the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `resize`:

```
std::string s = /* ... */;

if (auto n = s.find(c); n != s.npos) {
  s.resize(n);
}
```

Comment: Mind you, that's [documented as linear complexity too](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize#Complexity); some implementations could choose to reallocate unconditionally (assuming you wish to reduce memory usage), others might only do so if the string shrinks below the reallocation threshold.

Comment: Well it still takes linear time, so it's not really much of an improvement over something like substr, but thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: Or you could use [std::basic_string::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) (first version with default second argument), which has the same theoretical (and, afaik, practical) complexity.

Comment: `std::vector::resize` is guaranteed not to reallocate when resizing down (in order to preserve the iterators). Could it be the same holds for the `string`? In any case, `resize` should be amortized O(1)

Comment: @Ap31:The standard does not impose the same requirement on `std::basic_string::resize`, and as far as I can see, the "documentation" referred to above is not drawn from the C++ standard.

Comment: @KushalAgrawal: Please show me *in the standard* where the complexity of `resize` is defined to be linear. I'm being serious; I can't find *any* statement of its complexity. Cppreference is a great site, but like any secondary source, it is not authoritative.

Comment: From [C++14 working draft (Nov. 2014)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) page 667: "If n <= size(), the function replaces the string designated by *this with a string of length n whose elements are a **copy** of the initial elements of the original string designated by *this" (bold font added by me)... this could imply linear complexity.

Comment: @NicolBolas, it's linear in the size of the new string formed after resizing. 
[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)'s another source I use for c++ reference which states that resize takes linear time.

Comment: @zett42: Implication means nothing. The "as if" rule easily allows implementations to not copy anything and just move some pointers around and write a new NUL character. Unless the standard has a *direct statement* about the complexity requirement, the implementations can do anything they want, so long as they get the same results. Without a statement about complexity, then we must assume it is implementation-defined (and therefore likely to be reasonable).

Comment: @KushalAgrawal: I asked for something *authoritative*, not another secondary source.

Comment: @NicolBolas `basic_string`'s specification leaves a lot to be desired because it dates from the COW-era, where even a shrinking `resize` may well require a full allocation+copy. A full paper is probably needed to completely clean it up.

Comment: @T.C.: Technically, `vector::resize` *also* has no complexity specification. Anywhere. So such a paper should clean that up too.

Answer (score 3):

The logical answer here is `basic_string::resize`. What the *standard* says about this function is:

> Effects: Alters the length of the string designated by `*this` as follows:
>
> - If `n <= size()`, the function replaces the string designated by `*this` with a string of length `n` whose elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string designated by `*this`.
> - If `n > size()`, the function replaces the string designated by `*this` with a string of length `n` whose first `size()` elements are a copy of the original string designated by `*this`, and whose remaining elements are all initialized to `c`.

Now, that looks very much like linear time. However, the standard does not specifically state that things will happen this way. They only state that it will be "as if" things happen this way. Therefore, an implementation is completely free to implement the shrinking version of `resize` by shifting one pointer and writing a NUL character. Nothing in the standard would forbid such an implementation.

So the real question is... are standard library implementations written by complete morons? It's certainly possible that they are. But it's probably wise not to assume so.

Personally, I'd just use `resize` on the assumption that the library implementers know what they're doing. After all, if they can't write an optimization as simple as that, then who knows what other things they're doing wrong? If you can't trust your standard library implementation not to do stupid things, then you shouldn't be using it in performance-critical code.

Comment: "are standard library implementations written by complete morons?" For the longest time, `<regex>` on gcc's default standard library was evidence of "yes, some of it was written by complete morons".  ;)

Comment: @T.C.: BTW, is that "timsong-cpp" GitHub page officially where issues are stored now, or is it just a 3rd party listing?

Comment: @NicolBolas That's my site :) (because I hate linking to a massive page for a single issue)

Answer (score 2):

> is there any "end" character for an std::string?

No. It is possible to define a `std::string` that is not null terminated. You won't be able to do a few things for such strings, such as treat the return value of `std::string:data()` as a null terminated C string <sup>1</sup>, but a `std::string` can be constructed that way.

> Can I make the end iterator point to the current character somehow?

To get a `std::string::iterator` point to a certain character, you'll have to traverse the string.

E.g.

```
std::string str = "This is a string";
auto iter = str.begin();
auto end = iter;
while ( end != str.end() && *end != 'r' )
   ++end;
```

After that, the range defined by `iter` and `end` contains the string `"This is a st"`.

If that is not acceptable, you'll have to adapt your code to check the value of the character for every step.

```
std::string str = "This is a string";
auto iter = str.begin();

// Break when 'r' is encountered or end of string is reached.
while ( iter != str.end() && *iter != 'r' )
{
   // Use *iter
   ...
}
```

<sup>1</sup> Thanks are due to @Cubbi for pointing out an error in what I stated. `std::string::data()` can return a `char const*` that is not null terminated if using a version of C++ earlier than C++11. If using C++11 or later, `std::string::data()` is required to return a null terminated `char const*`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and very detailed answer :)

Comment: You could simplify the code to just `auto end = std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), 'r');` so you get either an iterator pointing to the first `'r'` or the original `end` iterator (using `std::find` instead of `string.find` means you don't even need to check return values). Still has to do the same work, so if you are processing as you go the explicit loop avoids iterating twice (once to find stop point, once to do work), but if you need to use the computed `end` many times, this simplifies matters, and the code is easier to read either way.

Comment: How do you imagine c_str not being usable as a C string?

Comment: @Cubbi: It would only be usable for C functions which take a pointer and a size argument. It would not be usable for something like `strlen`, which expects to encounter `'\0'` at a valid address.

Comment: @Cubbi, from [`std::string::c_str()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str). *
`c_str()` and `data()` perform the same function." From [`std::string::data()` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data): *The returned array is not required to be null-terminated.*. That's what a user has to deal with when a `std::string` does not have a null character in it.

Comment: The returned array is absolutely required to be null-terminated. Pay attention to "before C++11" and "since C++11" tags on both pages. c_str is always null-terminated, data is null-terminated as of C++11

Comment: Latest edit is stil wrong, c_str() was always required to be null-terminated. Before and after C++11. It was data() that changed spec.

Comment: @Cubbi. I see the difference now.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` does not have an "end character" like c style strings.  You can have many null terminators inside a single `std::string`.  If you want to the string to end after a certain character then you need to [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) the rest of the characters in the string after that last character.

In your case that would give you something like

```
string_variable.erase(pos_of_last_character + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR, is there any "end" character for an std::string? Can I make the end iterator point to the current character somehow?

Not really. `std::string` uses the [`std::string::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) function to keep track of the number of characters stored and maintained independently of any *sentinel characters* like `'\0'`.

Though these are considered when a `std::string` is initialized from a `const char*`.